# Python Dispatcher Definitions in a Function

Tags: python

I'm running into issues with Python dispatcher definitions changing each time I add a new function to the dispatcher. An example:

```
def dispatcher_create():
    dispatcher = {}
    for i in range(5):
        def square():
            return i**2
        dispatcher[i] = square
    for j in range(5):
        print dispatcher[j]()
    return dispatcher
```

This code prints out the value `16` five times. I was hoping it would print out `0 1 4 9 16` instead. I'm sure it's an issue with me redefining `square` every time, but I'm not sure how best to fix it.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Sorry and thank you. Indentation fixed.

Comment: This is a well-known Python gotcha: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 2):

The `i` in `return i**2` is bound to the *name* `i`, not the *value* `i`.

Try this to create a new variable, bound to the appropriate value:

```
def dispatcher_create():
    dispatcher = {}
    for i in range(5):
        def square(i=i):
            return i**2
        dispatcher[i] = square
    for j in range(5):
        print dispatcher[j]()
    return dispatcher

dispatcher_create()
```

Answer (score 2):

No, redefining `square()` every time is doing what you want, which you can check by printing the contents of `dispatcher`: all the functions in it will have different id's as desired.

The problem is that you're creating a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) so when you call any of the functions stored in `dispatcher` they are accessing the latest value of `i`, rather than using the value that `i` had when they were defined.

Robᵩ has shown one way around that, by passing `i` as an arg to `square()`; here's another way: using *another* closure which takes `i` as an arg so it can preserve it for the squaring function it makes.

```
def dispatcher_create():
    dispatcher = {}
    def make_square(j):
        def square():
            return j**2
        return square

    for i in range(5):
        dispatcher[i] = make_square(i)
    return dispatcher

dd = dispatcher_create()
print dd

for j in range(5):
    print dd[j]()
```

**typical output**

```
{0: <function square at 0xb73a0a3c>, 1: <function square at 0xb73a0dbc>, 2: <function square at 0xb73a0d84>, 3: <function square at 0xb73a5534>, 4: <function square at 0xb73a517c>}
0
1
4
9
16
```

Robᵩ's version is a little simpler, but this version has the advantage that the functions in `dispatcher` have the desired argument signature, i.e., they take no argument, whereas Robᵩ's functions take a single argument with a default value that you can over-ride.

FWIW, you *could* use `i` instead of `j` as the parameter for `make_square()`, since it's just a local variable to `make_square()`. OTOH, using `i` there shadows the `i` in the outer scope, and I feel that using `j` is slightly less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with scope. The i variable remains defined after the for cycle it is used in. If you print the value of i after the for cycle, you see it is 4. If you then call the functions in the next for cycle, the value of i that is in the current scope is used.

As for the solution, i think functools.partial would be a good choice.

```
from functools import partial

def dispatcher_create():
    dispatcher = {}
    for i in range(5):
        def square(value):
            return value**2
        dispatcher[i] = partial(square, i)
    for j in range(5):
        print dispatcher[j]()
    return dispatcher
```